# Identifying co-locating groups

Tags: r, correlation

I am relatively new to R, so I'm sorry if my post is unclear in advance. 
I have a data frame like this:

mydata <- data.frame(Town=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C", "C","C","C"),
                     Industry=c("A","B","F","A","C","B","G","B","G","T","A","C","F"))

My real dataset has 5000 observations, 400 towns and 90 industries.

```
mydata <- data.frame(Town=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C", "C","C","C"),
                     Industry=c("A","B","F","A","C","B","G","B","G","F","A","C","F"))

   Town Industry
1     A        A
2     A        B
3     A        F
4     B        A
5     B        C
6     B        B
7     B        G
8     C        B
9     C        G
10    C        T
11    C        A
12    C        C
13    C        F
```

And I want to identify combinations of industries that co-locate with at least two other industries in the same regions, 50%/ more than 50% of the time. If identified, I would want the unique combination of the industries.

For example, if industry A located in 10 towns and industry B and C co located in 5 out of those 10 towns, then they will be classified as a cluster, made of A,B and C. Ideally in data frame form with the unique combinations.

I tried to do this for a while but the closest I got was performing co-occurrence matrix but failed to get the unique combinations and calculating the correlation was not consistent. My real dataset has 5000 observations.

My attempt so far.

```
df2 <- crossprod(table(df[1:2]))
diag(df2)<- 0

df3<- melt(df2)
```

Comment: Have you added the c language tag for a reason? (Just wondered)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Fash30115. Could you please give us more example code of what you've tried? How did you code the co-occurence matrix, for example?

Comment: Yep, I added how I made the co-occurrence matrix with the edit. The C tag was by accident, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the difference between row 10 and row 13? Also this is a distance problem,  since there are only three towns in your example, 50% means 1.5 towns. Assuming the data is correct, then we could do do:

```
n <- length(unique(mydata$Town)) # Number of Towns:

m <- as.matrix(n - dist(table(mydata[2:1])>0)^2) #number of cities they share in common

data.frame(as.table(m))[c(lower.tri(m) & m >= (0.5 * n)),]

   Var1 Var2 Freq
2     B    A    3   # B and A share 3 Town
3     C    A    2   # C and A share 2 Towns
4     F    A    2
5     G    A    2
8     C    B    2
9     F    B    2
10    G    B    2
15    G    C    3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm sorry I didn't clarify enough but the example data is only an example. My real dataset has 5000 observations, 400 towns and 90 industries.and not as simple/easy as the one in the example. Would this still work?

Comment: @Fash30115 yes it should work. That will be a matrix 90*90. That is a small matrix